# Adding a custom column to a knex query with PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm very new to writing queries in general for PostgreSQL, much less Knex, so I appreciate any help somebody can provide.

PostgreSQL `v10.12`
Knex `v0.20.13`
Node `v12.16.0`

Say I have a DB with entries such as:

```
id   |  int1  |  int2
_____________________
1        5        10
2        6        15
```

And my knex query looks something like this:

```
db // This is my knex connection
  .from('items AS item')
  .select(
    'item.id',
    'item.int1',
    'item.int2'
   )
```

How would I go about adding a column to my results that would SUM int1 and int2?

```
id   |  int1  |  int2  |  sum
_______________________________
1        5        10       15
2        6        15       21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in order to not skip a step.

The query that we want to build with Knex is:

```sql
Select id, int1, int2, (int1 + int2) as sum from items;
```

This query will fetch all the regular columns of `items` and add a new column with the name `sum`.

In order to build this query using Knex:

```js
db.select('id', 'int1', 'int2', db.raw('(int1 + int2) as sum')).from('items');
```